# Using Intellij, launching a "Flash App" run configuration, how do I add arguments to make the flash player start a specified size?

Tags: flash, intellij-idea

When running an swf in Flashdevelop, I can specify the dimensions that the flashplayer will open in using the projects properties.

[image]

I would like to specify these dimensions in IntelliJ. I figure this can be done somewhere in the run configuration?

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add [SWF] metadata to your main class:

```
[SWF(width="512", height="512")]
public class MySprite extends Sprite {
    ...
}
```

or

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Metadata>
        [SWF(width="512", height="512")]
    </fx:Metadata>
    ...
</s:Application>
```